# Jacob and Jesus

Tags: history, prophet-isa, prophet-yaqub

As a Muslim it is my understanding that Jesus was born to Mary(P.B.U.T) and the person who took care of him was Zakaria. However, I am reading a book on Jesus (written by a Christian) that claims it was Jacob who took care of Jesus. It never mentions Zakaria. I wonder how and where this relationship between Jacob and Jesus came into existence.

Comment: You should note though, the Jacob who raised Jesus in the Bible is *not* the prophet Jacob (Yaqoub). They just shared the same name.

Comment: Also, Zakariyya (as) took care of Maryam (as), not Jesus (as).

Comment: Correction. The man who raised Jesus in the Bible was named Joseph and is (also) not the prophet Joseph (Yusuf).

Answer (score 1):

According to bible script, I think it is Joseph the carpenter who help Marry (A.S) to raised Prophet Jesus (A.S). Bible mention that Marry was engaged with Joseph and then the miraculous birth of Prophet Jesus happened. For the records, Holy Qur'an  doesn't have any record for the Marry (A.S) marriage and for Joseph the carpenter.

Don't mix this Joseph with Prophet Joseph (A.S). They are different people.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest suggest you check out our help-center.  Please note, that the bible is not a source of Islam, nor a source for answers here on this sit.

Comment: Ok ... But Brother asked for both account and I tried to tell him with my little knowledge. Anyway, will be careful next time.

Comment: As Bible is not source of Islam, but is honored in Holy Quran. "Ask those who read the book revealed before thee." Sura 10:94. Whether or not it is prescriptive, it shows some respect to Scripture which was written before Holy Quran.